# Как рандомно выбрать фото и подпись к ней?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, случайные-числа

Суть проблемы такая: надо с помощью функции `random` запросить элемент из словаря типа

```
some_dict = {'text1': 'photo1', 'text2': 'photo2', 'text3': 'photo3'}
```

и передать текст в `message`, а фото, соответствующее подписи, в `attachment` (vk_api, если что)

P.S Кому не сложно, скажите, правильно ли я составила вопрос?

Comment: "правильно ли я составила вопрос"... почти ) не стОит называть переменные зарезервированными словами (такими, как dict или list), и в квадратных скобках получился бы список, не словарь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) из пакета random. Для нее нужна индексируемая последовательность, поэтому сначала преобразуйте в список:

```
import random

some_dict = {'text1': 'photo1', 'text2': 'photo2', 'text3': 'photo3'}
text, photo = random.choice(list(some_dict.items()))

>>> text
'text3'

>>> photo
'photo3'
```